# How to use VBA to open a website on chrome on Mac

Tags: vba, excel

I am newbie to VBA and do not have a solid coding background so I would really appreciate some help here.

I am trying to use VBA to open a website on Chrome on Mac and I got the following code

```
Sub ip()
    Dim chromepath As String
    chromepath = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/reports/infringement"
    Shell chromepath & url
End Sub
```

But the system always shows there is an error from the Shell line: path not found. It becomes really frustrating. Does anyone know what's the problem?

Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't know much about Mac, but did you notice that you concatenate chromepath and url without adding any space between them? Try Debug.Print chromepath & url before the line starting with Shell.

Comment: Also, are you sure that's the correct path to Chrome? _also not a Mac user_

Comment: Try `Shell chromepath & " " & url`

Comment: I tried `Shell chromepath & " " & url` but it was showing the same thing.

Comment: Also, I am sure the chrome path is correct because without the 
`Dim url As String
 url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/reports/infringement"`
the code is able to run. It will bring out the chrome browser.